# Image in footnote too wide, although set width=textwidth

Tags: footnotes, width, includegraphics, textwidth, linewidth

If I put a graphic in a footnote and apply `width=\textwidth` to it, it will be **wider than the actual text width** (see MWE below). (The same holds true for `\linewidth`.)

Apparently includegraphics measures the width of the area in the main text and not in the footnote. Since the footnote number and some spaces before it reduce the actual width of the footnote, it doesn't fit anymore.

It is possible to work around this error by subtracting the overfull width from the image width (i.e. `width={\linewidth}-2em`, this may require `\usepackage{calc}`). But it should actually work without this intervention. Or what am I doing wrong?

**MWE-Code:**

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry} % to see pagelayout 
\begin{document}

Placing an image in main text with \texttt{width = textwidth} results correctly in:\\
\includegraphics[ width=\textwidth, height=50pt ]{example-image-a}

But placing an image with \texttt{width = textwidth} in the footnote not.\footnote{\includegraphics[ width=\textwidth, height=50pt ]{example-image-b}}

\bigskip

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent vel auctor turpis, at commodo diam. Aliquam fermentum leo at erat congue, a porta ex congue. Quisque eget facilisis felis. Proin bibendum ultrices ante quis faucibus. Vivamus quis rutrum augue, in semper tellus. Duis porttitor enim tortor, a fringilla arcu rhoncus eu. In luctus nisi id odio placerat, nec pellentesque ligula rhoncus. Maecenas imperdiet dictum odio ut finibus. Proin egestas a ex eget auctor. In eget enim eleifend, fringilla leo vulputate, laoreet mi. Suspendisse potenti. Morbi faucibus risus ut nunc lobortis imperdiet. Aliquam nec ultricies nulla. Aenean feugiat libero nisi. Nam eget dapibus tortor.\footnote{Pellentesque nec varius dui. Quisque malesuada nunc id velit pulvinar, eu mollis metus auctor. Phasellus quam dolor, varius id iaculis nec, aliquam a urna. Cras imperdiet elit erat, vitae tincidunt velit commodo vel. Praesent sit amet justo rutrum, tincidunt nibh in, venenatis lacus. Vivamus sit amet turpis velit. Integer faucibus vestibulum augue sed mollis.}

MWE:

\end{document}
```

**MWE-Output:**

[image: MWE includegraphics in footnote too large]

Comment: `\textwidth` is just a length, and its value the width of the *typeblock*. But the first line of a footnote is shorter because of the space taken by the indent / box of the footnote number.

Comment: Echoing the previous comment: the textwidth of the footnote block is the actual width of the text there, i.e., from "dolor" in the second line up to "Praesent". The image has this width so it works as expected. If you want a less wide image you can use for example `width=0.9\textwidth` which does not require the `calc` package. This type of adjustments is regularly done in LaTeX, it may not be fully precise but it gives the same result and is much easier than the alternative (something like finding the footnote number indent and the width of the number and subtracting them from the textwidth).

Comment: Thanks @Iacobus1983 for the explanations that \textwidth is a fixed width! I didn't know that. I thought the variable would automatically calculate the available width. Isn't there a simple and short way to specify the available text width? This would be the answer for my question.

Answer (score 2):

You need to take account of the paragraph indent and footnote counter. You could calculate the amount but tex tells you:

```
Overfull \hbox (15.3142pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 9--9
```

so adjust by that

```
But placing an image with \texttt{width = textwidth} in the footnote
not.\footnote{\includegraphics[ width=\dimexpr\textwidth-15.3142pt, height=50pt ]{example-image-b}}
```

produces

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your solution. I was hoping there was a way to automatically calculate the actual "text width".